# Como funciona callback em PHP?

Tags: php, callback

Estava estudando um pouco de PHP até eu me deparar com esse código:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("nome", "nome", "required|min_length[5]|callback_nao_tenha_a_palavra_melhor");

public function nao_tenha_a_palavra_melhor($nome) {
    $posicao = strpos($nome, "melhor");
    if($posicao != false) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message("nao_tenha_a_palavra_melhor", "O campo '%s' não pode conter a palavra 'melhor'");
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Dentro da função de validação do formulário é passado como parâmetro um `callback` que chama outra função.

Já li a documentação do PHP mas fiquei com dificuldade pra entender. Um `callback` é usado pra chamar como parâmetro uma função dentro de outra função, é isso ?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um callback nada mais é do que o nome ou referência a uma função que é passado como parâmetro para outra função, sendo invocada quando for conveniente. No php podemos fazer isso utilizando a função nativa call_user_func para chamar uma função pelo nome. Um callback então no php pode ser usado da seguinte forma:

```
function funcaoCallback($a){
  echo $a;
}

function funcaoQualquer($callback){
  //Faz algo aqui e quando tiver pronto chama a função que foi passada
  //com um parâmetro gerado dentro desse método
  call_user_func($callback, 'teste');
}

funcaoQualquer('funcaoCallback'); // exibirá teste como saída
```