# Como funcionam as callbacks e funções anônimas em PHP?

Tags: php, callback, função-anônima

Boa tarde,

1. Como funciona uma função anônima em PHP?
2. Como funciona a *callback* em PHP?
3. Como trabalhar os dois em conjunto? (função anônima e *callback*)

   Eu estudei um pouco de JavaScript e achei bem diferente no PHP aplicar essas 
   *callback*, parecem serem mais complexas que em JavaScript, poderiam me dar uma 
   definição e exemplos, pois consultei a documentação (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.closure.php) e não entendi bem ao certo.

Comment: Item 2 — [Como funciona callback em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122409/99718),

Answer (score 1):

As [funções anônimas](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php) do PHP funcionam semelhantemente como as expressões de função ([function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)) do javascript.

A **função anônima** é usada geralmente como callback mas não se restringe somente a isso, ela também pode ser usada em casos específicos de seu código como, por exemplo:

*Realizar um comportamento específico dentro de uma função que será útil apenas para este escopo.*

```
$addition = function($num1, $num2) {
    return $num1 + $num2;
};

echo $addition(5, 5); //10
```

---

A *Callback* é o uso de uma função como parâmetro de outra função, permitindo o uso da callback assim que necessário. Um bom exemplo de uso de uma callback é a função [array_map](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-map.php).

```
public function getFilename()
{
    $files = ['wallpaper', 'user-photo', 'nude'];

    $appendJpg = function($name) {
        return $name . '.jpg';
    };

    $filesJpg = array_map($appendJpg, $files);

    print_r($filesJpg); //Array ( [0] => wallpaper.jpg [1] => user-photo.jpg [2] => nude.jpg )
}
```

---

Funções anônimas implementadas a partir da versão do PHP 5.3 produzem objetos do tipo [Closure](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.closure.php) que oferece métodos para manipulação da função. Um **Closure** permite herdar variáveis do escopo pai (escopo da função onde o closure está declarado) utilizando a instrução `use`.

```
$name = 'Victor';

$fullName = function($lastName) use ($name) {
    return "$name $lastName";
};

echo $fullName('Carnaval'); //Victor Carnaval
```